# Using ramda pipe with react

Tags: reactjs, ramda.js

I have this sort of composition with ramda & react where a is some container component & x,y & z are HOC.

```
export default R.pipe(
    x,
    y,
    z
)(a)
```

every component being,

```
const x,y or z = C => props => <C {...props}/>
```

If I want to inject a couple extra parameters to y component, how do I do that?

Comment: Please create a better example. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @OriDrori edited it.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this are static parameters, you can wrap component `y` with another function:

```
const y = extraParams => C => props => <C {...{...props, ...extraParams }}/>
```

And call the function when composing:

```
export default R.pipe(
  x,
  y({ param: 20 }),
  z
)(a)
```

Comment: ok, so that's the only way.   I have done the same.  Can this be done with something like R.curry on the fly?

Comment: How will you pass changed props on the fly? You can do it in the component before it, but not from outside.

You can use R.curry, but it's not really a good use. In this case the extra params should always be separate from the component and props, and R.curry is not classic curry (single param in each call).